# Timestamp creation/deletion when data from multiple selected cells is deleted

Tags: excel, vba, timestamp, cell, erase

I have some code in VBA that is used to create/delete a timestamp in Excel when a user edits the contents of a cell that lies within a specified range. It works in the background and does not need to be consciously activated by the user (no key commands).

However, this only seems to work if the user is editing exactly one cell. When more than one cell is selected and the user deletes the content (not the cells themselves), it pops up an error and prompts the user to debug the code.

My code is hobbled together from some other online resources, so I do not claim to completely understand what is happening, but there is a line of code  that causes the error, it appears twice in my code, and it reads:

```
If Target.Value = "" Then
```

I think this is basically stating that the timestamp should be recorded/deleted when the cell the user has edited is empty. I think it is only looking at one cell at a time, perhaps due to the

```
For Each Cell In Target
```

and

```
Next Cell
```

parts of the code.
How do I passively activate the timestamp code when someone deletes information/text from one or more cells without then causing this error?

My complete code:

```
Public Sub DocChange(ByVal Target As Range)
' Auto Date
Dim Cell As Range 'Create the "Cell" dimension as a range
For Each Cell In Target 'Within our range, wherever we might click into a cell, we want to do the below stuff
    If Target.Row <> Range("A:A").Row Then 'If the selection is not in the first row
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then 'And it is not blank
            Range("last_update").Value = Now 'Place the current time and date into the cell labeled "last_update"
            Range("Last_User").Value = Environ("username") 'Place the username of the current user making the edit into the cell labeled "Last_User"
        End If
'            If Target.Column = 11 Then 'If the selection is in column 11 (K)
'                If Target.Value = "" Then 'And if the cell is blank
            If Target.Column = 11 Then 'If the selection is in column 11 (K)
                ActivationStatus Target
'                    If Cell.Value = "" Then 'And if the cell is blank
'                    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Value = "" 'Then delete the date in the next column
'                End If
            End If 'And end the if loop
    End If
    If Cell.Row <> Range("A:A").Row Then 'If the cursor is placed not in Row 1
'    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
        If Cell.Value = "" Then 'And that cell is emptied
'        If Target.Value = "" Then 'And that cell is emptied
            Range("last_update").Value = Now 'Place the current time and date into the cell labeled "last_update"
            Range("Last_User").Value = Environ("username") 'Place the username of the current user making the edit into the cell labeled "Last_User"
        End If
    End If
Next Cell 'Cycle to the next cell, basically telling the program to start looking for the next input
Application.EnableEvents = True 'Make sure that the user can perform operations within the doc
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Make sure that whatever has and will be done can be seen in the doc
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub ActivationStatus(ByVal Target As Range)
            'If Target.Column = 11 Then 'And it is in the 11th column (K)
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                If Cell.Value = "Active" Then 'And it has "Active" in it
                    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Value = Date 'Then put the today's date next to it
                ElseIf Cell.Value = "Not Released" Then 'Or if it has "Not Released" in it
                    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).ClearContents 'Then clear the date next to it
                ElseIf Cell.Value = "No Status" Then 'Or if it has "No Status" in it
                    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).ClearContents 'Then clear the date next to it
                ElseIf Cell.Value = "Obsolete" Then 'Or if it has "Obsolete" in it
                    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).ClearContents 'Then clear the date next to it
                ElseIf Cell.Value = "" Then
                    Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).ClearContents
                ElseIf Cell.Value = "Tested" Then
                        If IsDate(Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column - 1).Value) Then
                            Target.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Else
                            MsgBox "The selected project has no date of activation." _
                            & Chr(10) & "Please ensure that the project has a" _
                            & " recorded date of activation before declaring it tested." _
                            & Chr(10) & " Not Released --> Active --> Tested", vbExclamation
                        End If
                    End If
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
            'End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: did you by chance change `Worksheet_Change` to `DocChange`?

Comment: Use `Cell` instead of `Target` within the loop.

Comment: If Target.Column = 11 Then ... But if Target is a range that possibly spreads across several columns, what does in mean to be equal to 11? You need cell here not target

Comment: `Cell` instead of `Target` has seemed to work. I am getting a different error but I am going to see what I can do to fix it. What is the difference between `Cell` and `Target` in terms of how VBA interacts with the document? I am curious as to why one works and the other does not.

Comment: `Target.Column=11` is intended to only look for changes to a particular column. Basically, when the user sets the project as "Active" in column K, I want the code to record a timestamp in the adjacent cell of column J. It also needs to delete the timestamp when "Active" is either deleted or changed to another value from a drop-down list.

Comment: @Fin O'Dea: `Target` means the changed range. If you change only a cell, `Target` = `Cell`. Otherewise `Cell` means each cell in `Target` range. Your function is an Event which is automatically triggered by any change in the document. If you need to have some code working when the "project" becomes active, you have to write code in the `Workbook_Activate` event. I must confess that "Active from a drop-down list" is Chinese for me...

Comment: @FaneDuru: Thank you for clarifying `Target` and `Cell`. The drop down list I mentioned is the Data Validation in Excel. The indication of "Active" is more internal project development indicator to the project team I am on and has no real bearing on the VBA code other than it being a string that is referred to in the code.

Comment: @BigBen: Does the name of the sub matter if I call the correct sub? I did change the name from the original code so I could make sense of all the subs I am using in this document.

Comment: Depends if you call it or if you want it to be executed automatically (as would happen if you don't modify the event handler of the [`Worksheet.Change`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) event)

Comment: @BigBen So, I do have the `Worksheet_Change` event and it calls the module for `DocChange` (as well as a few others). I wanted to have one basic code for each task or operation, then call those as needed for each sheet. That way I can update the specific code once and it will operate the same across sheets (theoretically).

Comment: Ahhhh. Gotcha. In that case, no issue with the naming.

Comment: I am still having issues with this column 11 thing. I have it now passing to another module when the user selects a range in column 11. That module checks the input and performs either a timestamp recording or deletion in the adjacent cell. This code (which I have added to the original question) breaks at `If Cell.Value="Active" Then` when you try to delete the contents of more than one cell in column 11. To be clear, I am not having this issue with any of the remaining document when you delete more than one cell in a row or column.